# Using a replace function in C programming

Tags: c

How do I write a replace function which takes a pointer to a string as a parameter and replaces all spaces in that string with minus signs?

example :

```
input = "I love pies", output = "I-love-pies"
```

Comment: `for (char *p = input; *p; p++) { if (*p == ' ') *p = '-'; }`

Comment: @tb1000 next time please share what you've tried.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant what a waste of characters. `void r(char*p){while(*p=32^*p?*p:45)++p;}`, function included. Let's not teach bad habits of writing huge unreadable walls of code :)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant may you explain the for loop statement, I understand everything after the curved brackets

Comment: @tb1000 so what don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int change_string(char *input) {
    for (char *p = input; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == ' ') *p = '-';
    }
    return 1; 
}

int main() {

    char input[] = "I love pies";
    printf("%s\n", input);
    change_string(input);
    printf("%s\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did you put '[]' after the input in 'char input[] = "I love pies";' ?

Comment: @tb1000 Because it's an array.